# Create a timer or alert which doesn't get affected by page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, timer, alert

I want to create a timer/alert in my website that prompts the user that its 1 hour since you logged in.
The timer shouldn't start from beginning when the page is refreshed. I tried using

```
setTimeout(function(){
  alert('signout!!');
}, 10000);
```

It works fine as long as I don't refresh the page. Any ideas are welcome. Is there any way to calculate the time from db? Im storing the log in time in db.

Thanks

Comment: How can i set the timer? Im sorry, Im just learning javascript. I mean, i know how to alert after a particular time. but i don't know how to at a particular time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution like this.
In `<head>` tag

```
<?php
                $cur_id = $_SESSION["cur_id"];      
                $st="select crStarttime, ADDTIME(crStarttime, '1:00:00') as en from callrecord where crID  = '$cur_id'";
                $rt = mysql_query($st);
                $r = mysql_fetch_array($rt);
                $starttime = $r['crStarttime'];
                $endtime=$r['en'];
            ?>      
            <script>
                var endtime = "<?php echo $endtime;?>";
            </script>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                function startTime()
                {
                    var today=new Date();
                    var h=today.getHours();
                    var m=today.getMinutes();
                    var s=today.getSeconds();
                    // add a zero in front of numbers<10
                    m=checkTime(m);
                    s=checkTime(s);
                    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML=h+":"+m+":"+s;
                    var curtime =h+":"+m+":"+s; 
                    t=setTimeout('startTime()',500);
                    if(curtime==endtime)
                    {                   
                        alert("Time to signout.");
                    }                       

                }
                function checkTime(i)
                {
                    if (i<10)
                    {
                        i="0" + i;
                    }
                    return i;
                }
            </script>
```

Then in the body

```
<div id="txt"></div> // just to print the current time.
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a cookie to store a start time. On page load you can check for the cookie, and set your timer accordingly.

When the timer hits the hour mark, or if the page loads after the mark has been reached, prompt the user and delete the cookie.

To set cookies in Javascript, check out this page:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: Deleting cookies can be a little tricky when you first learn to use them, but this optins beat a PHP Session variable and much faster to implement and maintain over storing in a DB.

Comment: How can i set the timer? Im sorry, Im just learning javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Tie your timer to a specific date/time -- on page load, find out the number of seconds remaining until that point in the future, and set your timeout accordingly. You can do the work on the client or server. Either way.

Comment: How can i set the timer? Im sorry, Im new to javascript.